# Jasmine/Jest-Like Describe Blocks in Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

Using a JavaScript testing framework such as Jasmine or **Jest**, I can organize the tests as such:

```
describe('someFunction', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // do some setup for each describe block
  })

  describe('some scenario', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // do some setup before each test case
    })

    test('some test case', () => { ... })
    test('another test case', () => { ... })
  })

  describe('some other scenario', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // do some setup before each test case
    })

    test('some test case', () => { ... })
    test('another test case', () => { ... })
  })
})
```

> I was wondering if there is a way to achieve a similar describe-block structure using the **Spock** testing framework with Groovy?

I know that I can have the outer structure fine, as such:

```
class SomeFunctionSpec extends Specification {
  def setup() {
    // do some setup before each feature method
  }

  void "some Function"() {
    given: "some setup before this test"
    // ...

    when: 
    // ...
    then: 
    // ...

    when:
    // ...
    then:
    // ...
  }
}
```

I feel like having too many when-then makes things too confusing and would like to separate the test cases in different feature methods, but under the same setup scenario. That way, I don't have to do the same thing in the given block every time (but also without affecting the outer block, without creating data that might affect the other scenarios).

Comment: Anything under `given: "some setup before this test"` can go to a private helper method inside the spec itself and then invoke that method in each feature method's `given:` or `setup:` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [Fixture Methods](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-4/spock_primer.html#_fixture_methods) in the Spock docs you can see, that `setup` is equivalent to `beforeEach`. What you don't do in Spock is to nest these, you can use inheritance if you want to have `setup` from the parent applied as well. And as you have said, using when-then repeatedly in a single test is in most cases a code smell. If you have that special case then you might want to look into `@Stepwise` in conjunction with `@Shared`.

Depending on you scenario you have several options.

1. Use the `setup` method to prepare common state
2. Use helper methods that are called in the `given`/`setup` blocks
3. Use 1 together with inheritance to combine `setup` methods

```
abstract class BaseScenarioSpec extends Specification {
  def setup() {
    // do some setup before each feature method
  }
}

class Scenario1Spec extends BaseScenarioSpec {
  def setup() {
    // do some setup before each test case
  }

  def "some test"() {
    when: //stimulus
    then: //verification
  }
}


class Scenario2Spec extends BaseScenarioSpec {
  def setup() {
    // do some setup before each test case
  }

  def "some other test"() {
    expect:
  }
}
```

Just note that tests that are declared in the base class, will be executed in the subclasses as well.

Comment: do I have to call super in the setup() for each inherited class?

Comment: great to hear that! by the way, should the second class be named Scenario2Spec? :)

Comment: testing with Spock in Grails 2.4.5, unfortunately, this does not seem to be supported. It's a nice idea and may work on newer builds? Grails 2.4.5 spock has convention around the name of the thing you're testing. if you have `FooController` your spec will need to be `FooControllerSpec` or the framework will fall over.